# Google Dataflow Template size cap at 10Mb

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I set up a template on Google dataflow and it ran fine. After some modification of adding parallel processing on partition, the template size grew much bigger. I tried to run it and it failed. I got some error like the following

`Template file 'gs://my-bucket/templates/my-template-name' was too large.  Max size is 10485760 bytes.`

Looked like gcp has a cap on the template size around 10 MB. Is there any way to increase the limit or compress the generated template? The update I did is pretty much create partition from a pCollection. Then each pCollection in this pCollectionList starts same structure of the transform and file write. Without partition, the size is 1.5 mb. partition to 4 paritions, it grew to 6 mb. When going for 8 partitions, it grew to 12 mb. Isn't this limited the complexity of the pipeline can be?

Here is some description on the partition. Origin process is like this
`String option -> pCollection as input files -> TextIO -> sort -> write`

After the partition is like

`String option -> pColletion as input files -> parition -> each partition does TextIO -> sort -> write`

The partition in the middle is the only major change. Why would this make the size of template grew few times bigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue for Dataflow. If you are using Beam SDK >= 2.9, you can add `--experiments=upload_graph` to the command you use to generate the template. It should help you generate a smaller template. However, I am not sure if this feature is fully available to all Dataflow users now, since it has just been implemented. If not, it may take a few weeks for it to be fully available.

Comment: Thanks so much. Do we know when this feature will be available or where can we see announcement for it ?

Comment: I don't think there will be an announcement for it. Whether this feature is available will depend on the region you run Dataflow. You can try this now and see if it is already working for you. I think it will at most take a few weeks for the feature to rolled out to all regions.